# Normal force - direction

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

How to determine direction of normal force on a ball falling from the table? What is the rule? Where is the contact surface?

[image]

Comment: I’ve hidden a number of comments that should have been posted as answers. Please use comments to improve the question; to answer a question, post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The normal force is always normal (i.e. perpendicular) to both surfaces. You may not be able to see the surface curvarture of the corner clearly without zooming in, but you *can* see it of the circle. Just draw the normal force from the contact point so it is perpendicular to the circle.

Surfaces practically always meet with flat surfaces against on another if you zoom in far enough. Meaning, a tangent throught the contact point will be a tangent to both surfaces. So drawing the perpendicular normal force to this tangent can be done based on any of the two surfaces. The only time you can't clearly point out the normal force direction is if two corners meet and you can't zoom in.

Comment: Sir if we have two rods meet then at point of contact can we not predict the direction of normal if yes why not ? As such we can zoom in to see that point- point contact is we need tangent to both surfaces isnt ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax Hi, I'm sorry, your question is a bit unclear. Are you referring to a situation where two thin rods meet end to end? If the rods are idealised as lines (or if you have zoomed far out), then you have lost information about the tip geometry, yes, and wouldn't be able to accurately predict the normal force direction. If you assume ideal rods ends you might argue for the journal force direction via symmetry, though.

Comment: Yeah sir i mean that only and yeah may you tell what by ideal you mean Sir here ? And what direction we can tell of those two end-end contact ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax By "ideal rod ends" I actually just mean that you have some idea of the geometry in mind and assume the ends to be exactly that. It could be perfectly cut-off flat. It could be a rounded end as a perfect sphere. In such cases you could from symmetry considerations deduce that the normals forces must be pointing along with the rods (assuming that they have contact in-line).

Comment: Hmm understood thanks Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Normal is self adjusting and which always acts perpendicular to the surface on the object and in this case we can't assume a surface easily so we will assume a surface on the sphere whose area is very very less and that's only possible in the case of tangent so the normal force will always act towards the center of the sphere and will be perpendicular to the tangent.

And because of the newton's third law the normal force will also act on the corner of the wall which will be applied by the sphere. Which will act just on that point where the sphere is making contact with the wall, and the thing what we call it as a "sharp corner" doesn't exist for the very very small objects for them it's nothing but just a curve whose radius tends to be nearly equal to zero but not exactly zero. so still it a curve. And the exact same case will happen with the normal force on the wall as of the sphere (i.e it'll also act perpendicularly to the tangent of the curve of the corner)